# Need last value from previous year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a query of patients' last blood pressure values of 2015.

When I use `max(date)` it includes values from 2016, but when I apply `where date < '2016-01-01'` it does not give me the values for those patients in 2015, but rather just deletes them from the results.

The query so far:

```
select distinct 
    pat.pat_last_name, 
    pat.pat_first_name, 
    pat.birth_date, 
    enc.bmi, 
    enc.contact_date, 
    enc.[weight], 
    enc.height, 
    pat.PAT_ID 
from 
    pat_enc enc 
    inner join patient pat on enc.pat_id = pat.pat_id 
    inner join (
        select pat_id, max(contact_date) as LastEncounter 
        from pat_enc 
        group by pat_id
        ) enc2 on enc.pat_id = enc2.pat_id and enc.contact_date = enc2.lastencounter 
where 
    enc.contact_date < '2016-01-01' and 
    enc.bmi is not null 
group by 
    pat.pat_last_name, 
    pat.PAT_FIRST_NAME, 
    pat.birth_date, 
    enc.bmi, 
    enc.contact_date, 
    enc‌​.[weight], 
    enc.height,
    pat.PAT_ID
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results are helpful.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Show your actual code and add your DBMS.

Comment: select distinct
pat.pat_last_name
,pat.pat_first_name
,pat.birth_date
,enc.bmi
,enc.contact_date
,enc.[weight]
,enc.height
,pat.PAT_ID

from pat_enc enc
inner join patient pat on enc.pat_id = pat.pat_id
inner join (select pat_id, max(contact_date) as LastEncounter from pat_enc group by pat_id) enc2
on enc.pat_id = enc2.pat_id and enc.contact_date = enc2.lastencounter where enc.contact_date < '2016-01-01'

and enc.bmi is not null 
group by pat.pat_last_name,pat.PAT_FIRST_NAME,pat.birth_date,enc.bmi,enc.contact_date,enc.[weight],enc.height,pat.PAT_ID

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.bloodpressures WHERE YEAR(Date) = 2015
```

Comment: Before that you should format the date string into a DATE datatype using TO_DATE(date, format)(in MySQL). Year function will then extract the year from that date.

Answer (score 0):

And to elaborate gabrielVas answer a bit further, since you asked specificely for the last value

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.bloodpressures WHERE YEAR(Date) = 2015
order by date desc
limit 1
```

Comment: @agalgay: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is you're only fetching the absolute maximum dates because of this:

```
select pat_id, max(contact_date) as LastEncounter
....
enc2.pat_id and enc.contact_date = enc2.lastencounter
```

The where clause only limits data after this matches.

To make it fetch data for 2015, you need to also get the max date from 2015:

```
inner join (
    select pat_id, max(contact_date) as LastEncounter 
    from pat_enc 
    where contact_date < '2016-01-01' 
    group by pat_id
    ) enc2 on enc.pat_id = enc2.pat_id and enc.contact_date =
```

Comment: thank you. That seemed to have corrected many, but there was one patient I kept using as a reference for success and he's still missing off this query even though he had a visit in August 2015.

Comment: had to add an 'is not null' in the where statement up above, too to ensure it was pulling actual office visits. all solved...THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `MAX` subquery you can simply apply a `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select
    pat.pat_last_name, 
    pat.pat_first_name, 
    pat.birth_date, 
    enc.bmi, 
    enc.contact_date, 
    enc.[weight], 
    enc.height, 
    pat.PAT_ID 
from 
    patient as pat 
    inner join
      (
        select *,
            row_number() 
            over (partition by pat_id 
                  order by contact_date desc) as rn 
        from pat_enc 
        where contact_date < '2016-01-01'
          and bmi is not null -- depending on your need might be moved to the outer WHERE
      ) as enc 
    on enc.pat_id = pat.pat_id 
where rn = 1
```

Btw, both `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` do exactly the same, you don't need it if `patient.pat_id` is unique.